# ROC Graph Construction

Tags: graph, svm

I have two heavily unbalanced datasets which are labelled as positive and negative, and I am able to generate a confusion matrix which yields a ~95% true positive rate (and inheritly 5% false negative rate) and a ~99.5% true negative rate (0.5% false positive rate).

The problem I try to build an ROC graph is that the x-axis does not range from 0 to 1, with intervals of 0.1. Instead, it ranges from 0 to something like 0.04 given my very low false positive rate.

Any insight as to why this happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I used Platt's algorithm to extract the probability of a positive classification and sorted the dataset, highest probability first. I iterated through the dataset, any positive example (real positive, not classified as positive) increments the truepositive count while any negative example (real negative, not classified as negative) increments the falsepositive count.

Think of it as the support vector on the SVM which separates the two classes (+ve and -ve) moving gradually from one side of the svm to the other. Here i'm imagining points on a 2d plane. As the support vector moves, it uncovers examples. Any examples which are labelled as positive are truepostives, any negatives are falsepositives.

Hope this helps. It took me days to figure out something so trivial due to the lack information on the net (or just my lack of understanding of SVMs in general). This is especially aimed at those who are using CvSVM in the OpenCV package. As you might be aware, CvSVM does not return probability values. Instead, it returns a value based on the distance function. You do not need to use Platt's algorithm to extract an ROC curve based on probabilities, instead, you could use the distance values themselves. Say for example, you start the distance at 10, and you decrement it slowly until you've covered all of the dataset. I found using probabilities better to visualise, so to each his own.

Please mind my english as it's not my first language

Answer (score 0):

In a ROC graph, the two axes are the rate of false positives (F) and the rate of true positives (T). T is the probability that given a positive data item, your algorithm classifies it as positive. F is the probability that given a negative data item, your algorithm incorrectly classifies it as positive. The axes are always from 0 to 1, and if your algorithm is not parametric you should end up with a single point (or two for the two datasets) on the ROC graph instead of a curve. You get a curve if you algorithm is parametric and then the curve is induced by different values of the parameter(s).

See http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/ROC/ROC.html

Comment: My problem is that I am using an SVM, which is not a probabilistic model. It simply classifies between positive and negative values, which is why I am ending up with one point only. Moreover, the SVM in OpenCV does not return the probability of a classification, only the distance function value. I am trying to use this value to determine a probability, no luck so far.